# How to check whether a username is available from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a query with which I am checking whether a username is available or not in one table

```
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from tb_sponsar where username='$username'");
```

But,I am having two more tables named tb_company and tb_school and both tables have this field named username now I want to have a query that checks usernames from all the three tables...I am new to php so don't know how to do it.can anyone please help me in this regard?

I tried it like this

```
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from tb_sponsar where username='$username'" && "SELECT * from tb_company where username='$username'");
```

but after applying this query it is giving false result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1,tabl2,table3 WHERE username='$username'`

Comment: it is checking the condition right from first table but is not working properly in second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tray using UNION keyword to combine tables:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT username from tb_sponsar where username='$username' UNION SELECT username from tb_company where username='$username'");
```

You can also use JOIN but you need to have a relation between those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from tb_sponsar where 
username='$username'" AND "SELECT * from tb_company where username='$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT username from tb_sponsar where username='{$username}'"
. " UNION SELECT username from tb_company where username='{$username}'"
. " UNION SELECT username from tb_table3 where username='{$username}'");
```

Comment: when i am applying this query it is showing the same result for every username that is not available even if the username does not exist

Answer (score 0):

try this bro

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from tb_sponsar where username='$username' AND SELECT * from tb_company where username='$username' AND SELECT * from tb_school where username='$username'");
```